# Remove php-5.6 on server debian 8

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian

I'm removing php-5.6 to upgrade >= php-7.

But I have a problem with config phpmyadmin.

[image]

I don't understand this message please help me. I don't want lost database.

Comment: Could you please give us the command line you are executing and the resulting output so that we can identify the best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that phpMyAdmin is about to be removed from your system as part of removing packages that depend on PHP5.6. If you provide the exact commands you're executing, as asked by Bruno Ramos, we can better help you through transitioning to PHP 7 without removing too many other packages.

At its root, this message is asking if you want to remove the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage database. If you plan to continue using phpMyAdmin on your system, you probably want to say no here.